# debug a shell script when passed as argument to another shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

i want to debug a shell script when passed as argument to another shell script

first.sh second.sh 100

i have place set -x in both the scripts 
 
but not able to debug the second script

Answer (score 1):

Since there is not much to go on here are some things to make sure

1. The first line of the scripts should say which shell you are using

> ```
> #!/bin/env bash
> ```

1. make sure that both scripts are executable.

> ```
> ls -l first.sh
> ls -l second.sh
> ```

the first columns should have -rwx------ at a minimum if not then make them executable with the following

```
chmod 700 first.sh 
chmod 700 second.sh
```

1. Make sure that first.sh is accepting the $1 and $2 paramters.

Error messages etc will help us help you :)